# Ubuntu 10.04 Python modules

Tags: python, directory, modules

I want to install lxml on an Ubuntu VPS, but I'm having problems. There is no site-packages directory where I can put lxml. How I am supposed to install it?

I tried doing:

`apt-get install python-lxml`, but it says that the package is unavailable, so I tried moving it there but I don't have site-packages folder. I'm running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS with Python 2.6, or more info:

```
> Python 2.6.5 [GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
```

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you give the error reports on running the `apt-get install python-lxml` command?.  Generally path where modules are stored `/usr/lib/`. For python modules try using the python based installers PIP, easy_install!

Comment: Hi, first thanks for the answer. The error is ""package 'python-lxml' doesn't exist"". I have a folder called dist-packages, but no site-packages. Maybe I should put them there? But the problem is that there are no modules there, only 3 files (in dist-packages).

Comment: Wow, I played with it an hour ago and it worked. You are awesome man, thanks, really!

Comment: How did yu do ? `PIP` or `easy_install`!